# Flutter Search Iterable Where

Tags: list, flutter, search

my json data

```
 [      
             {
                "receive_brutto" : 10,
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "id_trx_procurement" : 1,
                        "item_group_id" : 3135,
                        "item_group_proc" : {
                            "name_group" : "Alpukat",
                            "uom_item_group_name" : "Kg"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id_trx_procurement" : 2,
                        "item_group_id" : 3135,
                        "item_group_proc" : {
                            "name_group" : "Apel",
                            "uom_item_group_name" : "Kg"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
]
```

how to filter data using iterable where method. for example i want to filter where element data `item_group_proc`, but `item_group_proc` in List `data`.

Comment: Please share your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: listItemReceive.map((element1) {
      element1.data
          .where((element2) => (element2.itemGroupProc.namegroup
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(text.toLowerCase())))
          .toList();
    });

@Riwen

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, convert the JSON into a Dart Model like this.

```
class UserDetails {
  int receiveBrutto;
  List<Data> data;

  UserDetails({this.receiveBrutto, this.data});

  UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    receiveBrutto = json['receive_brutto'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['receive_brutto'] = this.receiveBrutto;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int idTrxProcurement;
  int itemGroupId;
  String dateProc;
  ItemGroupProc itemGroupProc;

  Data(
      {this.idTrxProcurement,
      this.itemGroupId,
      this.dateProc,
      this.itemGroupProc});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idTrxProcurement = json['id_trx_procurement'];
    itemGroupId = json['item_group_id'];
    dateProc = json['date_proc'];
    itemGroupProc = json['item_group_proc'] != null
        ? new ItemGroupProc.fromJson(json['item_group_proc'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id_trx_procurement'] = this.idTrxProcurement;
    data['item_group_id'] = this.itemGroupId;
    data['date_proc'] = this.dateProc;
    if (this.itemGroupProc != null) {
      data['item_group_proc'] = this.itemGroupProc.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class ItemGroupProc {
  String nameGroup;
  String uomItemGroupName;

  ItemGroupProc({this.nameGroup, this.uomItemGroupName});

  ItemGroupProc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    nameGroup = json['name_group'];
    uomItemGroupName = json['uom_item_group_name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name_group'] = this.nameGroup;
    data['uom_item_group_name'] = this.uomItemGroupName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Once this is done then you can manage the JSON accordingly. For eg.

```
UserDetails userdetails = new UserDetails.fromJson(response);
```

Comment: Thanks before,
I don't mean that, I've made a model like that before, only, what I want is, filtering List <Data>, but List <Data> is inside userDetails

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that get raw data and return response and you can use this function to access the data whatever you want like that;

```
FutureBuilder<UserDetails>(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  snapshot.data.item_group_proc
```

Comment: `listItemReceive.forEach((element1) {
      element1.data.forEach((element2) {
        if (element2.itemGroupProc.namegroup
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(text.toLowerCase()) ||
            element2.trxProcurement2.userProc.user.name
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
          tmp2 = element2;
        }
      });
      element1.data.add(tmp2);
      tmplistItemReceive.add(element1);`

like this, but that code error, you can solved ?